# how to include Bootstrap.css in angular2 final release

Tags: angular

I am trying to include bootstrap.css locally in angular2 final release.

I put bootstrap.css in dist/assets/css folder.

In index.html i put

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

But its not working.

Dont know whats wrong.

project is generated through angular-cli.

Plz help.

thanks[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `angular-cli` you can follow steps given on [Global Library Installation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#global-library-installation) to update your `angular-cli.json`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't place it in dist folder. Place it somewhere else, u can place inside app/assets.. During build dist folder is overridden.